# Watershed segmentation to define river midline

Tags: watershed

I need to define the midline of a river in a RGB Landsat image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6AsG.png). I obtained a binary image and the distance from background (riverbed), and tried to define the peaks to use as markers for watershed, but got stuck. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the peak_local_max?

```
img = cv2.imread('lsat01.tif') 

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
T,binary = cv2.threshold(gray,45,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.figure;plt.imshow(binary, 'gray')
kernel = np.ones((6, 3), np.uint8)
dil = cv2.dilate(binary,kernel,iterations = 2)
ero = cv2.erode(dil,kernel,iterations = 2)
cv2.imshow('erosion',ero)

distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(ero)
plt.figure;plt.imshow(distance, 'gray')

rmax=peak_local_max(distance, indices=False,footprint=np.ones((9,9)), labels=gray)
plt.figure;plt.imshow(rmax, 'gray')
```